# Github repeats commit again in a pull request with different ID

Tags: git, github, merge, rebase

I have one repo in github the last commit is

```
Refs #12345 - AFS functional tests basic structure 
commit ddca57d27a6dc29a1857232bf51b737d348dbcf9
author author1
```

Then in local I have reset the master branch to be equal to master in origin

```
git checkout -B master origin/master
```

so the last commit in local is the same

I create a new branch and add a commit chaging two files

```
Preparing readme
 commit 08cc67393f4e121ae06b3cbd08e1bf01db490ddc 
author: me
```

but in the pull request apairs again the last commit is the same but with different sha1

```
Refs #12345 - AFS functional tests basic structure 
commit ee7a228dea9ef1efacc10ad921dcba0f7ee4d3b5
author: author1
```

The rebase and merge action has no conflicts, and also the merge, but I do not understand this situation

Comment: The hash IDs are the "true names" of the commits. This means you have two *different* commits that just look a lot alike. The GitHub web interface is not as clever as the command-line one (or various GUIs) and may not be able to show you the difference, except for the hash ID being different.

Comment: That right, but I copuldn't make a commit in my branch authored by other people, and also I was looking for something related to this: https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-request-merges/

Comment: As sayr the previous link: "Rebase and merge on GitHub will always update the committer information and create new commit SHAs, whereas git rebase outside of GitHub does not change the committer information when the rebase happens on top of an ancestor commit."

Answer (score 0):

Is your local repo synced with the remote github repo ?

Try running :

```
git fetch
```

an then inspect in a viewer where `yourbranch`, `master` and `origin/master` are :

```
# gitg and gitk are graphical viewers :
gitg yourbranch master origin/master
gitk yourbranch master origin/master

# you can have a pretty usable viewer using some of 'git log' options :
git log --oneline --graph --decorate yourbranch master origin/master
```